# Can we draw a line graph using core plot or any other graph library with my requirement?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, graph, core-plot

My requirements:

1) I need to draw a graph with date as xAxis and tracking result value as yAxis in which I need multiple points indicated for a day for different-2 time tracking and a scatter graph that is drawn on the basis of the average for that particular day as in iMoodJournal App.

[image]

2) I need to export the graph to image or customised pdf in which I need the full graph not only the graph that is displayed on the screen means I need the hidden part as scroll also in the image.
I am succeeded to export to image as the graph is displaying on screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following code to take screen shot of the part of the graph which is not visible:

```
- (IBAction) renderScrollViewToImage
{
     UIImage* image = nil;

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_scrollView.contentSize);
     {
         CGPoint savedContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
         CGRect savedFrame = _scrollView.frame;

         _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
         _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.contentSize.width, _scrollView.contentSize.height);

         [_scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
         image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

         _scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
         _scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
     }
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     if (image != nil) {
         [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: @"/tmp/test.png" atomically: YES];
         system("open /tmp/test.png");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not cater to all your requirements, but I would recommend [LineGraph](https://github.com/myCodeHurts/LineGraph) which serves first point.

Once you have the graph in a view, you can create memory bitmap and save it as UIImage.

EDIT:

Use below code to convert UIView to UIImage.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to create memory bitmap of that type in which we save it full graph as UIImage instead of screen display.

Comment: If you use LineGraph which creates UIView, I have put in additional code to convert into image.

Comment: I think it only capture the currently displayed screen not the full screen :)

Comment: You should be able to send the parent [UIViewController view] as a argument and can get the image. If you share the exact code on github or some where, I may be able to help more...

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy I will definitely share code and again ask you about it, if I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Core Plot.

1. There are many examples of line plots (scatter plots) in the example apps included with Core Plot. It has many options to customize the appearance of the graph.
2. To make a graph larger than the screen, *don't* add it to a hosting view. Size the graph layer as big as you need and set up the plot space to show all of the data. Use the `-imageOfLayer` method to create an image of the graph or `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` to create a PDF.

Comment: At first thanks for your reply
1) Can you add any example app link or name of the example for iOS from the example that can help me to fulfil my requirement.
2) If there is some code or a link that shows this that is more helpful.

Comment: The *Plot Gallery* example app has samples of every plot type supported by Core Plot. For the off-screen render, set the graph up exactly like you would if you were displaying it on screen, but do not add it to a hosting view and set the size as big as you need for the final image.

Comment: @EricSkroch its possible to drag and drop plot in core-plot framework

Comment: @Nagarajan Ask this as a new question.